# Bug or Feature in TextBlock in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, textblock

I have been having some fun with TextBlock bindings in Silverlight 4.
I have the following situation:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=g}" />
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=g}"/>
<TextBlock>
```

Where `Date` is a property of type `System.DateTime`.
I haven't changed the current culture of the application.

The culture of my machine is Bulgaria (bg-BG).
For example:

> TextBlock 1: 11/16/2011 12:49 PM
>   TextBlock 2: 16.11.2011 г. 12:49 ч.

The interesting thing is that the first `TextBlock` formats the date and time using en-Us culture (or the default invariant one) while the second one uses bg-BG culture.
Thing get even stranger since [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for Silverlight TextBlock control says:

> If the InlineCollection is created from XAML as inner text of a TextBlock object element, or **if it is created by setting the Text property, the InlineCollection contains a single Run that contains that text**.

**Am I missing something here or it can be considered bug in Silverlight 4?**

Comment: Strange indeed. Have you noticed the Text property of the Run class is not a DependencyProperty? I'm wondering how the binding works in this situation. I've tried placing a converter in both bindings and in the Run binding the culture parameter passed to the Convert method is NULL. I would say this is a Bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found that you need to make sure that the `Language` of the control is set correctly to get it to honour the language settings correctly. In our case it was for currency symbols, but I assume the same problem occurs for dates as well.

Tim Heuer has a [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) entitled "StringFormat and CurrentCulture in Silverlight" about this.

The solution is to add the following line to the view constructor:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

This doesn't explain why it works correctly for the `<Run>`